# Make IntegrationFlowBuilder process file when file is fully loaded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have an application which download a file to a specific location. And have another application which read the file using IntegrationFlowBuilder from that location , I want my second application to process only when file is fully loaded.
Here is how my second application consume the file.

```
        FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec fileInboundChannelAdapterSpec = Files
                .inboundAdapter(Paths.get(dir.toFile(), comparingLong(File::lastModified));

        fileInboundChannelAdapterSpec.patternFilter(pattern.get());

        fileInboundChannelAdapterSpec.preventDuplicates(true);
        
        IntegrationFlowBuilder integrationFlowBuilder = IntegrationFlows.from(fileInboundChannelAdapterSpec);
```

is there any why to achieve this by modifying something in **integrationFlowBuilder** .

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if your first application writes the file via a tmp one, and then rename it to the target name when it is done with writing a content to the file. So, the target file won't be visible for a polling application until it is renamed respectively.

Another trick would be achieved via `LastModifiedFileListFilter`:

```
/**
 * The {@link FileListFilter} implementation to filter those files which
 * {@link File#lastModified()} is less than the {@link #age} in comparison
 * with the current time.
 * <p>
 * The resolution is done in seconds.
 * <p>
 * When {@link #discardCallback} is provided, it called for all the
 * rejected files.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @author Artem Bilan
 *
 * @since 4.2
 *
 */
public class LastModifiedFileListFilter implements DiscardAwareFileListFilter<File> {
```

Although this is not fully reliable way sine you can't guess in advance how long the file is written.

Other way would be done via some file locking trick, but with that you would need to modify a producer app again.

See more info about filter in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-reading